# How to write validation code for range of numbers in a C sharp console app?

Tags: validation, console

I'm a budding C sharp programmer and I'm trying to write some validation code for a console app. I have written some code for the user to enter a number between 1 - 4. What I want to do is how can I write some code to prompt to the user to enter only numbers between 1 - 4 if they enter any numbers outside this range?

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: So you've wrote `Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1-4");` and you're wondering where to go from there?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply(was expecting email notification). That is correct. I have a variable incidentType which I assign the value from a user input using Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

Given you have supplied no code...

```
var number = 0
while(number < 1 || number > 4) 
{
   // send a message, Please enter a number between 1 and 4
   number = // get your number
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, sorry for the late reply(was expecting email notification.  I have a variable incidentType which I assign the value from a user input using Console.ReadLine(); If I use the code you supplied and I build solution, I get the error message "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'" This seems to be the problem I have as the Console.ReadLine() reads my input as a string and the comparison operator does not like it.

Comment: convert your string to a number  Convert.ToInt32(myString)